# How do I work around the fact that the nginx alias directive isn't allowed in named location blocks?

Tags: nginx

My goal is to cache assets with query strings with a certain policy and assets that don't have query strings with another. Unfortunately, nginx ignores query strings in location blocks, so I'm stuck using the `if`/`error_page` strategy helpfully suggested [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/811912/can-nginx-location-blocks-match-a-url-query-string/811981):

```
location /static/ {
    alias /home/client/public/;
    error_page 418 = @long_lived_caching_strategy;

    if ($query_string = "example=querystring") {
      return 418;
    }
  }

  location @long_lived_caching_strategy {
    etag off;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
    expires 1y;
  }
}
```

However, my error logs show me that in the above configuration, the `alias` directive is ignored. But when I try to move the `alias` directive into the `@long_lived_caching_strategy`, nginx tells me that `alias` isn't allowed there!

What are my options for a workaround?

Alternatively, is there another way to set `etag` and `add_header` directives differently depending on whether the URL has a query string?

Comment: Do you really send "418 I'm a teapot" often enough to bother with findng a complicated way to add error caching? If a proxy cache gets this, and you later use that URL, it could be a year before anyone sees content.

Comment: You were completely right, I thought that I could use return/error_page to divert requests with query strings to a named location block, but that came with the side effect of a 419 response code. Duh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an easier solution to my problem thanks to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/749321/nginx-alternative-to-if-inside-location-blocks-for-caching-headers-based-on-a) thread. My goal was really to conditionally add caching-related headers based on whether or not there was a query string, and using `if` to set strings turned out to be the easiest way to achieve that. Here's my final configuration:

```
  location /static {
    alias /usr/local/etc/nginx/relative-paths/picasso/client/public;

    # If an asset has a query string, it's probably using that query string for cache busting purposes.
    set $long_lived_caching_strategy 0;
    if ($query_string) { set $long_lived_caching_strategy 1; }

    if ($long_lived_caching_strategy = 0) {
      # Cache strategy: caches can store this but must revalidate the content with the server using ETags before serving a 304 Not Modified.
      set $cache_control "no-cache";
    }

    if ($long_lived_caching_strategy = 1) {
      # Cache strategy: proxy caches can store this content, and it's valid for a long time.
      set $cache_control "public, max-age=86400, s-maxage=86400";  # 1 day in seconds
    }

    add_header Cache-Control $cache_control;

    # Some types of assets, even when requested with query params, are probably not going to change and should be cacheable by anyone for a long time.
    location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc|ttf)$ {
      add_header Cache-Control "public max-age=86400, s-maxage=86400";
      etag off;
      access_log off;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this manually, if you have the [headers_more](https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module) module compiled into Nginx, for another way to make add_header available. Some distributions will include this, you may have to [build Nginx from source](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-2-setting-up-aws-for-wordpress-with-rds-nginx-hhvm-php-ssmtp/#nginx-source) - which is surprisingly quick and easy.

```
add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=691200, s-maxage=691200";
```

You don't need to use the expires header - [reason is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799906/what-s-the-difference-between-expires-and-cache-control-headers).

Comment: Good to know! But I would prefer to avoid any complexity in the installation process, as that would involve updating not just my nginx config, but also my deploy process.

Comment: It's easy to test if add_header always works on your Nginx distribution using "curl -i" to show response headers. It's not compiled by default in Nginx, but some distributions will include it. Amazon Linux's version doesn't, but there are distributions that do.